# How to access property in viewmodel from html?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a viewmodel as follow :

```
define(
    ['jquery', 'knockout', 'knockout.mapping', 'data/data', 'infra/store', 'infra/util', 'nls/nls', 'models/models'],
    function ($, ko, mapping, data, store, util, resources, models) {
        var
            post  = {},

            getPost = function (param) {
                $.when(data.deferredRequest('postDetail', param.id))
                 .done(function (result) {
                     mapping.fromJS(result, {}, post);
                 });
            };

        return {
            post   : post,
            getPost: getPost
        };
    });
```

and html file for the above as follow

```
<section id="section-post-detail" class="view">
    <div class="page-header">
        <label data-bind="text: post.title"></label>
    </div>
</section>
```

I applied the viewmodel to the html file, however title label in the html does not show any value even though title property in the post object has a value.

Did I miss something?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789224/how-to-access-property-on-object-in-viewmodel-from-html-code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
<label data-bind="text: post().title"></label>
```

Because the post property is an observable, it's important to invoke post() as a function (to obtain its current value) before attempting to read sub-properties.